# Initialize user home folder on Windows with commandline

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a local user on a Windows 2019 Server, `myuser`, but no home folder AKA `C:\Users\myuser`.

I preferably want to use native PowerShell to create the folder, but if there is some kind of exe file I could use, that is fine. I need it to be non-interactive.

I've looked at:

```
New-LocalUser -Name myuser1 -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString Password123! -AsPlainText -Force)
Get-Command -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts
net.exe user myuser2 /add Password123!
net.exe user myuser3 /add Password123! /homedir:C:\Users\myuser3
```

`New-LocalUser` provides no ability to create the home folder. Neither does `net.exe`. And there is no other usefull commands in the `Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts` module.

Note that what I'd really like to do is initialize the home directory when the user already exists, not create a new one.

My only options seem to be interactive logon, or interactive `runas.exe /profile /user:myuser whoami.exe` (this will prompt for password).

Creating the home manually, e.g. `mkdir C:\Users\myuser`, creates a folder that doesn't actually become the users home. If the user interactively log on after mkdir something like `C:\Users\myuser.MYCOMPUTER` is created as the real home folder.

Comment: Are you sure the folder doesn't already exist?  When you are creating the new folder a different names is being created because it already exists.

Comment: Yes, they don't exist. Windows is somehow creating the alternative name when logging on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start a process (cmd /c) as the created user, it will create his profile.

`$Cred = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new("myuser", (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password123!" -AsPlainText -Force))`

`Start-Process "cmd.exe" -Credential $Cred -ArgumentList "/C"`

Comment: Looks like I have to do some modification to make this work. Password is expected to be a `SecureString`. This works `$Cred = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new("myuser", (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password123!" -AsPlainText -Force))`. Looks like the `-LoadUserProfile` isn't needed.

Comment: ok, I edited my answer. Does it works ? The homedir is created ?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it works for me. I'm quite baffled if Windows really doesn't have a simple command that triggers profile/home folder creation. I'll mark this as the answer if no one else shows up with something that directly is meant to solve the issue.